# Какой порядок выполнения операций и почему?

Tags: c#, битовые-операции, операторы

```
static class Program
{
  static void Main()
  {
   var x=3;
   var y=(++x)*(x++)|4/2^2;
   Consoley.Write(y);
 }
}
```

Comment: [Приоритет и порядок оценки](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/2bxt6kc4(v=vs.140).aspx)

Comment: такс..получается x++,++x,*,/,| ?

Comment: @Nikita, XOR пропустили

Comment: ++x,x++,*,/,^,| ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

В соответствии с приоритетами слева направо:

```
(++x) * (x++) | 4 / 2 ^ 2

      ^
^^^^^ +--------------------- x=4, returns 4
      | ^^^^^--------------- x=5, returns 4
      `--------------------- 4*4=16
              ^
              |   ^
              | ^-+--------- 4
              |   | ^------- 2
              |   `--------- 4/2=2
              |       ^----- 2^2=0
              |       | ^--- 2^2=0
              |       `----- 2^2=0
              `------------- 16|0=16
```

PS: Надеюсь, не ошибся.